What happens when you use Lucas reagent on aromatic alcohols?
Usually tertiary alcohols immediately give a precipitate with the Lucas reagent ($\ce{ZnCl2}$ in concentrated aqueous $\ce{HCl}$) because the tertiary carbocation is more stable. But aromatic carbocations are more stable. So what happens if a secondary aromatic alcohol like the one below is submitted to the reagent?


Chemistry wise, protonation of the benzyl alcohol and its leaving would create a benzyl cation.

@Buttonwood I am aware that benzyl cation will bw formed. But will it also immediately form a precipitate

From wikipedia:

The differing reactivity reflects the differing ease of formation of the corresponding carbocations

The rate of formation of benzylic carbocations are nearly as fast as tertiary carbocations (see this answer). In this case, they may form even faster, as it is a secondary center. Presumably the benzylic alcohol so formed precipitates in the solution. I am unable to find references for this exact reaction.

That is the same situation I am in. I also thought along the same logic but couldn't find any references
